# Prove that there exists a $x>0$ such that $x^x = c$ WITHOUT using Intermediate Value Theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, real-numbers

I want to prove that there exists $x>0$ such that $x^x = c$ for $c>1$, and that it is unique. I have no idea how to begin, and I want to try to prove it without using the intermediate value theorem, as I do not how to show that $x^x$ is continuous for $x>0$, and I also want to see whether there is proof that solely relies on the properties of $\mathbb{R}$ as an ordered field and completeness (i.e. how Rudin shows the existence of $n$th roots in *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* Chapter 1). Can someone help?

Comment: You can't just rely on the properties of $\Bbb R$ as an ordered field.  You'll need completeness as well.

Comment: $x^x \ge e^{-1/e} \approx 0.6922$ when $x \ge 0$ so there is no $x$ for smaller $c$

Answer (score 1):

This function is not surjective, and not always injective.

That said, you could try to prove that the function is monotonic on an appropriate interval, then look at the least upper bound of the places where the value is less than $c$. (You need the completeness, not just the ordering.)

Comment: Ok, I get why it is increasing for $x>1$. Now let $A=\{t\in\mathbb{R}\,:\, t^t < c\}$. Since $1^1 = 1 < c$, $A$ is not empty. Also, if $t>c$, then $t^t > t > c$ so $t\notin A$, so $c$ is an upper bound of $A$. Then let $x = \sup(A)$. Now I am stuck.

Comment: You will have to show something essentially equivalent to continuity - that if the value at the supremum isn't exactly $c$ it is smaller and there's a slightly larger $x$ where the value is still smaller. I haven't thought about how to do that. (Look at the corresponding proof that $2$ has a square root using the supremum argument.)